# Using lookahead with greedy regex

Tags: regex

If I had a string such as "1) test 1 22) test 2 333) test 3 4444) test 4 55555) test 5", is there a lookahead regex to split and keep `(\d+\)`)?

I tried `(?=(\d+\)))`, which non-greedily split numbers by digits rather than `(\d+)`. Ex. 2) and 22) are both `substrings` of `(\d+\)`).

```
1) test 1 
22) test 2 
333) test 3 
4444) test 4 
55555) test 5
```

Comment: Do you mean [`(?=\b\d+\))`](https://regex101.com/r/xO3rB7/1)? Or perhaps, [`(?=(?!^)\b\d+\))`](https://regex101.com/r/xO3rB7/2)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a word boundary:

```
(?=\b\d+\))
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xO3rB7/1)

Note that here a sequence of digits should be preceded with a non-word character.

To trim the start,  just restrict the `\b` with a negative look-ahead `(?!^)`:

```
(?=(?!^)\b\d+\))
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/xO3rB7/2)

As `\b` may match the empty string at the start of the string (between the start and a word character), `(?!^)` look-ahead makes sure there is no match at that position so that we do not get an empty element.

Comment: I posted the suggestion as an answer. Also, note that if you are using Java, you need to specify the `(?U)` flag with the pattern to make it fully compatible with Unicode data. In Ruby, it is better to use `\A` to indicate start of string as `^` indicates the start of line by default.

Answer (score 1):

You use this lookahead based regex:

```
(?!\A)\s+(?=\d+\))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wT8eP6/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
(?!\A)    # We are at start of input
\s+       # Match 1 or white-space
(?=\d+\)) # lookahead to make sure next position has digits and )
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

```
(?=\b\d{2,})
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kW9xU2/3)

Or perhaps this which will match each line:

```
.+?(?=\b\d{2,}|$)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kW9xU2/2)